# When to use extern "C"?

Tags: c++, extern-c

I know how to use `extern "C"` but what are the conditions when you have to use it?

> `extern "C"` tells the C++ compiler not to perform any name-mangling on
>   the code within the braces. This allows you to call C functions from
>   within C++.

For example:

```
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    char d[6];

    strcpy_s(d, s);
}
```

While this compiles fine on VC++. But sometimes this is written as:

```
extern "C" {   
#include <string.h>  
}
```

I don't see the point. Can you give a real example where `extern "C"` is necessary?

Comment: Instead of hacking `<string.h>` to avoid name mangling, use the `<cstring>` header.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: If you write C++, use `<cxxx>`. If you write C, use `<xxx.h>` and **compile your code with a C compiler**. Mixing languages is *not* a good idea.

Comment: @user974191: I've never had to wrap a standard C library `#include` inside an `extern "C"`. Standard C library headers take care of checking if `__cplusplus` is defined and adding `extern "C"` for you. Where you might have to wrap in `#include` inside `extern "C"` would be a 3rd-party C library that didn't do the `#ifdef __cplusplus` checking for you.

Comment: @AlexandreC.: your advice is all association and no reasoning. it's dumb.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: What if you prefix `std::` in front of every function you call from a `<cxxx>` header? Can there still be portability problems?

Comment: @Emilie: Yes. Because that's a *convention*. And conventions are not checked by the compiler. A convention is especially likely to be broken when there is a long established convention doing the opposite. People tend to do things on automatic, unfortunately. Like, I "upvoted" your comment now in an on-automatic attempt to reply to it, pretty silly, yes?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Feel free to automatically upvote any of my stuff anytime. :-P

Answer (score 7):

You use `extern "C"` to prevent name mangling inside header files and your C++ object files *for libraries or objects that have already been compiled without mangling.*

For example, say you have a `widget` library which was compiled with a C compiler so that its published interface is non-mangled.

If you include the header file as is into your code, it will assume the names *are* mangled and those mangled versions are what you'll tell the linker to look for.

However, since you'll be asking for something like `function@intarray_float_charptr` and the `widget` library will have only published `function`, you're going to run into problems.

However, if you include it with:

```
extern "C" {
    #include "widget.h"
}
```

your compiler will know that it should try to use `function`, the non-mangled version.

That's why, in header files for C stuff meant to be included in C _or C++ programs, you'll see things like:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
#endif

// Everything here works for both C and C++ compilers.

#ifdef __cplusplus
    }
#endif
```

If you use a C compiler to include this, the `#ifdef` lines will cause the `extern "C"` stuff to disappear. For a C++ compiler (where `__cplusplus` is defined), everything will be non-mangled.

Comment: why is there a second `#ifdef __cplusplus` for?

Comment: @user974191: it's for the closing brace, otherwise the braces would be unbalanced.

Answer (score 4):

One very common use of `extern "C"` when you are exporting a function from a library. If you don't disable C++ name mangling you can otherwise make it very hard for clients of your library to name your function. And likewise, when going in the other direction, when you are importing a function that has been exported with C linkage.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a concrete example of where things break and need `extern "C"` to get fixed.

**`module.h`**:

```
int f(int arg);
```

**`module.c`**:

```
int f(int arg) {
  return arg + 1;
}
```

**`main.cpp`**:

```
#include "module.h"

int main() {
  f(42);
}
```

Since I am mixing C and C++, this won't link (of the two object files, only one will know `f` under its C++ mangled name).

Perhaps the cleanest way to fix this is by making the header file compatible with both C and C++:

**`module.h`**:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
#endif

int f(int arg);

#ifdef __cplusplus
  }
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

When you link with libraries that are written in C `extern` tells the compiler not to decorate the names so that the linker can find the functions. In C++ function names et al have information for the linker e.g. argument types and sizes contained in the name.

Answer (score 1):

If you are producing a binary library A that exposes a function that you would like to call from binary B.

Imagine A is A.dll and B is B.exe and you are on a Windows system.

C++ does not describe a binary layout such that B knows how to call A. Typically this problem is worked around by using the same compiler to produce A and B.  If you want a more generic solution you use the extern  keyword.  This exposes the function in a C manner.  C does describe a binary format so that different binaries from different compilers can talk to each other.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 1):

If, inside your C++ code, you `#include` a header for an external library (coded in C) and if the functions there are *not* declared `extern "C"` they wont work (you'll get undefined reference at link time).

But these days, people coding C libraries and providing header files for you tend to know that, and often put the `extern "C"` in their header file (suitably protected with `#ifdef __cplusplus`)

Perhaps a better way to understand is to use (assuming you have a Linux system) the `nm` utility to show you the (unmangled) names used in a library or an executable.